# Perl: String-substitution by string

Tags: regex, perl

I try to substitute a string.

```
my $str = "1abc9";
$str =~ s/abc/ABC/g;
print $str;
```

This prints out 1ABC9 - what I expect.

Is there a way I can have the whole mapping in one string?

```
my $map = "abc/ABC";
$str =~ s/$map/g;     # does not work
```

Comment: `s/$pattern/$replacment/g;`? Part of the problem with your proposal is how to identify the delimiter between the pattern and replacement? Seems pretty gnarly to me.

Comment: Why do you need it? `s///` doesn't take a single string, it takes a pattern and replacement.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Please elaborate on the motivation behind the question to get the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, no, for the same reason you can't do the following:

```perl
my $op = "+";
my $sum = $a $op $b;
```

You can't replace arbitrary code with a variable.

But the pattern part of `s///` is a regex literal and the replacement part is a double-quoted string literal, and both of those support interpolation, so you can use the following:

```perl
my $pat  = "abc";
my $repl = "ABC";
$str =~ s/$pat/$repl/g;
```

You could also create a sub. Even an anonymous one.

```perl
my $transform = sub { $_[0] =~ s/abc/ABC/gr }

$str = $transform->($str);
```